# Decrypt bytestream with Smartcard in Windows

Tags: c#, encryption, smartcard, pkcs#11

i created some encrypted bytestreams (files) with C# and BouncyCastle API. 
To be precise i created some CMSEnveloped data and stored that data on disk as bytestream.

Everything works as intended. SO far so good.

Now i want to use the private key stored on a siemens smartcard to decrypt some files.
For Encryption i can use the certificate stored in the domain information of that user.

But for decryption i have to use the smartcard somehow.

At the moment i can only think of using Siemens HiPath Developer API to access the private key via PKCS#11. But i have a feeling that there is a possibility to access the key via built-in windows certification store like outlook does with encrypted mail since this is basically also CMSenvelop / SMIME.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What card is that exactly? Which ATR sends it?

Comment: I do not think that this matters. It is a siemens card os 4.3B chip on it. CardOS Api is installed so Windows can import Certificates from the card.